# Can I configure clang-tidy to accept certain dead-store values other than NULL?

Tags: c, winapi, static-analysis, clang-tidy, resource-disposal

For example, the following function that uses the Windows API to load a file into memory and calculate its CRC32 checksum with a polynomial defined elsewhere as `POLYNOMIAL`:

```
#include <Windows.h>


UINT32 WINAPI GetFileCRC32(WCHAR *wszFileName, LPDWORD lpdwError)
{
    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LARGE_INTEGER liSize;
    DWORD dwError, dwRead;
    SIZE_T cbAlloc, i, i2;
    BYTE *bBuffer = NULL;
    UINT32 uCRC = 0xFFFFFFFFU;

    hFile = CreateFileW(wszFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
        goto cleanup;
    }
    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &liSize);
    do
    {
        cbAlloc = min(liSize.QuadPart, ALLOC_MAX);
        bBuffer = (BYTE *) HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, cbAlloc);
        if (NULL == bBuffer)
        {
            dwError = ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
            goto cleanup;
        }

        if (!ReadFile(hFile, bBuffer, cbAlloc, &dwRead, NULL))
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
            goto cleanup;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < cbAlloc; i++)
        {
            uCRC ^= bBuffer[i];
            for (i2 = 0; i2 < 8; i2++)
            {
                uCRC = (uCRC >> 1) ^ ((uCRC & 1) ? POLYNOMIAL : 0);
            }
        }

        HeapFree(hHeap, 0, bBuffer);
        bBuffer = NULL;

        liSize.QuadPart -= cbAlloc;
    }
    while(liSize.QuadPart);
    dwError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
cleanup:
    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
    if (bBuffer != NULL)
    {
        HeapFree(hHeap, 0, bBuffer);
        bBuffer = NULL;
    }
    *lpdwError = dwError;
    return uCRC;
}
```

Clang-Tidy, by default, does not detect the `bBuffer = NULL` line as a dead store, I assume because it recognizes the practice of setting a pointer to `NULL` as a defensive programming practice to prevent double-free bugs. However, I also set the value of `hFile` back to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` after closing it, as part of the same pattern.

However, clang-tidy does complain about the assignment of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (which is the numeric value `-1` coerced into a `HANDLE`) at the end of the function as a "dead store".

How can I configure clang-tidy analysis to accept values other than `NULL` as exempt from the dead store analysis?

Comment: Can we get a [mcve] rather than *"Here's my code, here are my assumptions, please help!"*?

Comment: How does the content of my question not constitute an MRE? 

There's no part of the included code that I feel is irrelevant

Comment: The "M" in "MRE" is for "minimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to configure the `clang-tidy`
[`deadcode.DeadStores`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/analyzer/checkers.html#deadcode-deadstores)
checker to ignore assignments of values other than `nullptr`.

The code that ignores `nullptr` assignments is at
[`DeadStoresChecker.cpp:340`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-17.0.6/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/DeadStoresChecker.cpp#L340):

```
      if (DeclRefExpr *DR = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(B->getLHS()))
        if (VarDecl *VD = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(DR->getDecl())) {
          // Special case: check for assigning null to a pointer.
          //  This is a common form of defensive programming.
          const Expr *RHS =
              LookThroughTransitiveAssignmentsAndCommaOperators(B->getRHS());

          QualType T = VD->getType();
          if (T.isVolatileQualified())
            return;
          if (T->isPointerType() || T->isObjCObjectPointerType()) {
===>        if (RHS->isNullPointerConstant(Ctx, Expr::NPC_ValueDependentIsNull))
              return;
          }

          // Special case: self-assignments.  These are often used to shut up
          //  "unused variable" compiler warnings.
          if (const DeclRefExpr *RhsDR = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(RHS))
            if (VD == dyn_cast<VarDecl>(RhsDR->getDecl()))
              return;

          // Otherwise, issue a warning.
          DeadStoreKind dsk = Parents.isConsumedExpr(B)
                              ? Enclosing
                              : (isIncrement(VD,B) ? DeadIncrement : Standard);

          CheckVarDecl(VD, DR, B->getRHS(), dsk, Live);
        }
```

The indicated line calls
[`Expr::isNullPointerConstant`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html#aa1d79a39abcf576a82b97cff17f893f8)
to check for `nullptr`, but there isn't any flexibility here to allow
other values.

At the end of the quoted snippet there is a call to `CheckVarDecl`,
which does a little more filtering based on the type of the variable
(ignoring references, for example) before issuing the report.  It
accepts the RHS expression but only uses it to get the source location
range; there is no filtering there based on the assigned value.

The only semi-feasible workaround I see is to wrap the assignment in a
call to an identity macro (`#define ID(x) x`), as the checker refuses to
report code that is inside a macro expansion.